# SSH via Cmder doesn't look in the right folder?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh, openssl, cmder

I'm facing an issue and I can't figure out what's going on.
To be brief, I'm on Windows 10 and I use a fresh Cmder install.

When trying to connect to my VPS server through SSH, I have the following warning:

> ```
> Could not create directory '/home/username/.ssh'
> ```

Obviously on Windows my `/.ssh/` folder is not `/home/username/.ssh` but `C:\Users\username\.ssh`.

I have verified and the folder already exists.

The strange thing is that my `%HOME%` environment variable seems to be correct.
When I type `echo %HOME%` in Cmder, the output is `C:\Users\username`.

I tried `ssh -v root@vpsXXXXXX.ovh.net -p 22`, here's the output:

```
λ ssh -v root@vpsXXXXXX.ovh.net -p 22
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015
debug1: Connecting to vpsXXXXXX.ovh.net [XXX.XXX.XX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
Could not create directory '/home/username/.ssh'.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to vpsXXXXXX.ovh.net:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XxXXxXxXXXXXXXxXxXxXxXXXXxXxxXxxXXxxXXxxXXx
The authenticity of host 'vpsXXXXXX.ovh.net (XXX.XXX.XX.XXX)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:XxXXxXxXXXXXXXxXxXxXxXXXXxXxxXxxXXxxXXxxXXx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I suspect an OpenSSH installation somewhere but I can't find it out.
Do someone have any idea?

**Update 1:**

Thanks for your advices @Maximus.
I realized it's not readable in the comments so here's what I tried.

As @Maximus suggested, I tried to run a basic ConEmu shell and I noticed some differences.
In a Cmder shell I ran:

`cd C:\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5 && ConEmu.exe -basic -run {bash}`

Then I tried to connect over SSH:

```
$ ssh -v root@vpsXXXXXX.ovh.net -p 22
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to vpsXXXXXX.ovh.net [XXX.XXX.XX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
```

It's not the same OpenSSH version and the keys folder path is OK.
The fact is I want to use Cmder, so if Cmder defines its own variables, how can I override them ?

Comment: Cmder defines its own variables. Try to run wsl/ssh from official ConEmu: `ConEmu.exe -basic -run {bash}`

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution to that problem.
After uninstalling a few chocolatey packages that I don't use anymore, Cmder look in the right path.

I uninstalled `android-sdk`, `genymotion`, `cmake`, `virtualbox` and `rsync`.
I don't really know which of them was problematic, but I highly suspect the `rsync` package.

I don't remember when and why I installed it, but I certainly made a mistake when playing with some config files.

Hope this could help someone someday.

Comment: Glad it helps you. But I'm curious to know which chocolatey package(s) you uninstalled ? Let me know please.

Comment: your comment of `highly suspect the rsync package` was correct. It was the culprit -_-

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Hiteshdua1

Comment: Uninstalling `rsync` fixed this for me also